# Display different view if visitor is from Google search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-referer

I am trying to accomplish something similar to the New York Times and other newsites that show full articles when a visitor is referred from Google but only shows the preview if it is a direct visit.

I believe that to check if a visitor is coming from google I need to check: `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]`.

Is this correct? Is it just a match on the name 'google'? Is the logic like this in the controller:

```
if request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].match "google"
  # do action/set variable etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you are pretty much right about all that. Just check via a regex if the user comes from google - and display the other site. Example code:

```
if request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] =~ /google\.[a-z]{2,4}/
  # do the special google stuff here
  render layout: "special_google_layout"
else
  # do the regular stuff here
end
```

This regex checks the referer for the string "google" followed by a dot and 2 - 4 small letters.